# Can I use this very old 9-pin monitor as a display in Linux?

Tags: linux, external-display, serial-port

I have a Packard Bell PB8810 desktop with a CTX CTX2422P 14" RGB Data Display.  The monitor connects with a 9-pin serial type connector.  I would like to figure out how I can drive this display with Linux, preferably Debian on a Raspberry Pi.

[image: Front of Monitor with Computer Powered up]

[image: Model info label on back of monitor]

Comment: That's probably a CGA monitor, which predates VGA.  AFAIK obtaining a video adapter for CGA that uses a modern bus (i.e. not ISA) could be impossible.  You have foremost have a hardware interface problem, not an OS issue.

Comment: @fixer1234:  It uses a 9-pin serial-port looking connect:  2-Rows, one with 4 pins, one with 5 pins.

Comment: The IBM PC used DB9 connectors for its CGA and EGA interfaces. This is not a "serial" (communications) interface.  DB connectors are generic; there is no specific or exclusive interface signals or protocol assigned.

Comment: Old CRT VGA displays are commonly available free these days, and would be much easier to find a device to drive them. Of course, it you are paying for the electricity, they are still "penny-wise, pound foolish" .vs. a flat-panel.

Comment: @Ecnerwal people around here trash old 14-19 inch LCD monitors because they are not "widescreen", look around a bit I bet you can find one for nothing, or close to it.

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm not using it to be thrifty, I'm planning on hiding a modern PC in or around this PC, and using it for aesthetics.  On my desktop I have a 4k 28" and I have plenty of old VGA LCDs on the shelf.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, well sort of... It is unclear if this is a CGA or EGA display though... You can use it if you have a video card that supports CGA or EGA output, which are typically only available as 8-bit ISA (PC/XT) expansion cards, occasionally 16-bit ISA cards. If you have an old computer with the appropriate card, Linux will work although X Windows (graphical interface) probably won't unless you have an extremely old distro (like mid-1990's). An example of a card would be the [ATi EGA Wonder](https://sites.google.com/site/atiwonderseriesdatabase/), although finding one could be tough as they were generally phased out in favor of VGA (which is still used today) by around 1990 or so. There is no USB or other adapter available that I am aware of to drive these monitors.